# Phalcon MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

`php7.0`, `Phalcon 3.2`, `MongoDB 3.2.14`

Хочу подключаться к базе, но в документации по Phalcon описана настройка подключения через MongoClient() и работа только через него, хотя он устарел давно и вообще deprecated в семёрке. Как мне подружить Phalcon с современным и уютным `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager()`? Потому что в `services.php` я ладно худо-бедно настроил, вроде не ругается, код такой:

```
/**
* MongoDB connection
*/
$di->set( "mongo", function () {
       $config = $this->getConfig();

        $db_string = sprintf( 'mongodb://%s:%s/%s', $config->mongodb->host, $config->mongodb->port, $config->mongodb->database );

        if( isset( $config->mongodb->user ) AND isset( $config->mongodb->password ) ) {
            $db_string = sprintf( 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s',
                $config->mongodb->user,
                (string)$config->mongodb->password,
                $config->mongodb->host,
                (string)$config->mongodb->port,
                $config->mongodb->database );
       }

        try {
            return new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $db_string );
        } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
            die( 'Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage() );
        }
    },
    true
);
```

А вот в моделях не нравится ему. Пишу в `app/models/User.php`:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Collection;

class User extends Collection
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('users');
    }
}
```

Вызываю в контроллере:

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo User::count();
    }
}
```

Пишет вот такое:

```
Call to undefined method ::selectcollection()
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::_getGroupResultset(Array, Object(User), Object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager))
#1 /var/www/testing/app/controllers/IndexController.php(8): Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::count()
#2 [internal function]: IndexController->indexAction()
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->callActionMethod(Object(IndexController), 'indexAction', Array)
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/testing/public/index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#7 {main}
```

Как победить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I installed Phalcon incubator using composer into my vendor directory:

```
composer require phalcon/incubator
```

Then I make sure that vendor libraries are loaded:

```
include_once SITE_ROOT . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then I use `\Phalcon\Db\Adapter\MongoDB\Client()` found in `vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter/MongoDB/Client.php`

In `services.php`:

```
$di->setShared('mongo', function () use ($config) {
    $mongo = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\MongoDB\Client();
    return $mongo->selectDatabase($config->mongodb->dbname);
});
```

Then ensure my MongoCollection extends `\Phalcon\Mvc\MongoCollection` (`vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/MongoCollection.php`).

`models/MyCollectionStats.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Common\Models;

class MyCollectionStats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\MongoCollection
{...
```

Ответ нашёлся [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716213/mongodb-and-phalcon-api?rq=1). Надеюсь,  дальнейшем это кому-то поможет :)